# Conditional inside C macro?

Tags: c-preprocessor

Is there any way to do this conditional at compile time instead of at runtime?

"flag" will always be a constant. A() and B() are macros.

```
#define DEMO(flag, p) if (flag) A(p); else B(p)
```

Why do I want to do this? Because macro A may or may not exist, depending on the underlying hardware (macro A controls hardware on a microcontroller).

If DEMO is called with "flag" *that evaluates to* false, it doesn't matter - it should compile. But if DEMO is called with "flag" *that evaluates to* true, I want to see a build error.

ADDED:

The intended use is like this:

```
DEMO(true, p);  // this should cause a build error
DEMO(false, p); // this should compile OK
DEMO(0, p); // should be OK
DEMO(1 == 2, p); // should be OK
DEMO(1 == 1, p); // should cause a build error
```

The passed parameter is always a constant, but not always the *same* constant.

Comment: "Always a constant, but not always the *same* constant." A **variable** constant, then.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there any way to do this conditional at compile time instead of at runtime?

Sure:

```
// add or remove this definition
#define flag

#if defined(flag)
   #define DEMO(p) A(p)
#else
   #define DEMO(p) B(p)
#endif
```

---

ADDED in response to OP's addition:

```
#define DEMOfalse(p) B(p)
#define DEMOtrue(p) A(p)
#define DEMO(flag,p) DEMO##flag(p)
```

This uses the "stringizing" operator (`##`) which replaces `##flag` with the actual source code text you call the macro with.

`DEMO(true,p)` will expand to `DEMOtrue(p)`, which expands to `A(p)`. If you pass `true` and `A` is not defined, your build will fail.

`DEMO(false,p)` will expand to `DEMOfalse(p)`, then `B(p)`, which will build whether or not `A` is defined.

---

EDIT in response to OP's edit:

A macro cannot contain preprocessor statements (well, it *can*, but they won't processed by the preprocessor), so there's no way to put a compile time conditional *in* the macro, hence the approaches shown above.

Comment: Thanks again, but that only works if the passed value is "true" or "false" (not any integer value that evaluates to true or false).  I updated the original question to clarify some more.

Comment: That's not possible. You specifically said they were *constants*, which is what makes this possible at all. See my edit. Also, this is starting to sound like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) because it's morphed into completely nonsensical things like `DEMO(1==2,p)`. We could probably help better if you made it more concrete, less abstract, because there's no way in hell you really need to evaluate `1==2` as part of your project. What problem are you trying to solve? What are the actual parameters you'll be using with this macro?

Comment: Sorry for oversimplifying. Of course I don't need to evaluate 1==2. I'm taking a parameter that may be trying to enable pull-ups on a MCU input pin. Some MCUs don't *have* pullups. So on such a MCU, passing a false (don't enable pullups) is valid, and doesn't need to generate any code (there are no pullups, therefore they don't need to be disabled). But if I try to pass a true, that should generate an error *at compile*. The actual parameter passed will likely be a macro ENABLE_PULLUPS or DISABLE_PULLUPS, defined as true or false, or 1 vs. 0.

Comment: Why would it be defined as true or false, or 1 or 0? If you want it to function as a compile-time boolean, you simply *define* it for true and *don't define it* for false, as in my first example. ENABLE_PULLUPS will be true/false, 1/0, defined/not, etc. for an entire translation unit, right? You can't change it like a variable -- it's a compile time constant. So how does the first example not work for you?

Comment: Unless we're talking past each other, no. Suppose I have 3 switches I'm defining, 1, 2, and 3.  1 and 2 might use internal pullups (so ENABLE_PULLUPS), while 3 uses an external pullup (so DISABLE_PULLUPS). But all 3 call DEMO: switch(1, ENABLE_PULLUPS); switch(2, ENABLE_PULLUPS); switch(3, DISABLE_PULLUPS). What I want is to get a build error if I attempt to enable pullups on an input that doesn't support that. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the whole macro body, you can create sub-macros to be conditionally-compiled:

Duplicate part of the code:

```
#ifdef FLAG
#    define COND_MACRO(a, b) ((a) == (b))
#else
#    define COND_MACRO(a, b) ((a) < (b))
#endif

#define MY_MACRO(a, b)
    if (COND_MACRO(a, b))
        do_smth();
```

Duplicate the whole code:

```
#ifdef FLAG
#   define MY_MACRO(a, b)
        if ((a) == (b))
            do_smth();
#else
#   define MY_MACRO(a, b)
        if ((a) < (b))
            do_smth();
#endif
```